# How do python pipe still work through spawning processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand why the following code **works**:

```
import multiprocessing

def send_message(conn):
    # Send a message through the pipe
    conn.send("Hello, world!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    # Create a pipe
    parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    # Create a child process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=send_message, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()

    # Wait for the child process to finish
    p.join()

    # Read the message from the pipe
    message = parent_conn.recv()
    print(message)
```

As I understand, python pipes are just regular OS pipes, which are file descriptors.
When a new process is created via **spawn** , we should lose all the file descriptors (contrary to regular fork)

In that case, how is it possible that the python pipe is still  "connected" to its parent process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation does not suggest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) that it will lose all the file descriptors - only that "unnecessary file descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited".  To figure out how this is achieved exactly in CPython, first we need to see what exactly happens when [`p.start()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L110) is called in the example code.

After some point upon starting the process, the `Process` instance's underlying `Popen` helper will be used, in the case for `'spawn'` it would be the version provided by [`popen_spawn_posix`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py#L26).  As part of the startup sequence goes, it will get the relevant data that is required to start the process, this includes which function to call and then their arguments ([code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py#L42-L47%5D)), which a specific [pickler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/reduction.py#L58-L60) is used.

Given that the `Connection` object (which `Pipe` is built upon of) has defined a [hook](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L972) that actually ensures the relevant file descriptor is [marked for duplication](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L966-L968).  This is ultimately invoked from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/reduction.py#L195) which points back to the helper function at the `'spawn'` version of the [`Popen.duplicate_for_child`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py#L34-L36), ensuring that any connection objects passed (in your case, `args=(child_conn,)`) will have their file descriptors passed through to the actual start function [`spawnv_passfds`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L447-L460) such that the child process will have access to them.

I will note that I have glossed over various other details, but if you wish to you can always attach a debugger and trace through the startup sequence, which is what I did to derive this answer.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense
In the meantime I realized that in linux there is also the O_CLOEXEC  flag, that could be activated or not on the fd. Potentially this could have been used instead, to just not close all the fd for the child process after exec

Comment: Probably, but do realize that `O_CLOEXEC` is relatively new, and that [underneath all this mess no `posix_spawn` is actually called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L453-L457) - either [`fork` or `vfork`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c#L736-L755) is called instead.  It's definitely [hard to get rid of `fork`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-fork-in-the-road/) ([direct link to publication](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/04/fork-hotos19.pdf)) apparently...

Comment: Actually, the more obvious reason is because Python wants to be sure that whatever open files user programs does managed to open within the Python process space (e.g. through some C extension) - those might not have been opened with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag and it's just simpler to remove everything manually.